# Api working local but not on production nextjs

Tags: next.js

I'm working with nextjs 13 and I have an api defined to send emails.

Everything is working locally but when I run npm deploy and npm start, the request returns a 404 error.

my api (pages/api/sendMail.js):

```html
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      const mensagem = req.body.mensagem;
      const subject = req.body.subject;
  
      // Check if the code is running on the server side
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        try {
          // Dynamically import nodemailer only on the server side
          const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  
          // Replace these values with your own email server configuration
          const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              user: process.env.SMTP_EMAIL,
              pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD,
            },
          });
        

          const mailOptions = {
            from: process.env.SMTP_EMAIL,
            to: process.env.SMTP_SEND_TO,
            subject: subject,
            html: "message"
          };

          const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
          console.log(`Message sent: ${info}`);
          
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      } else {
        print('This code is running on the client side')
      }
    } else {
        print('This code is running on the client side')

    }
  }
```

I'm calling this function like this:
`const response = await fetch('/api/sendMail', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }, body: JSON.stringify(message), });`
and my next.config.js is `module.exports = { output: 'export', trailingSlash: true, distDir: 'out', pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx'], }`